# SQL Server 2016 non clustered index is not being used while ordering on clustering index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, b-tree

Could you please explain to me why this nonclustered index is not being used when querying together with ordering on clustered index?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table]
(
    [NPId] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [RequestDate] [DATETIME2](2) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [TINYINT] NOT NULL,
    [StatusCodeId] [SMALLINT] NULL,
    [NumberCount] [INT] NULL,
    [Number] [BIGINT] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_NPLog_1] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NPId] ASC)
               WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ReqDate] 
ON [dbo].[table] ([RequestDate] ASC)
INCLUDE ([NPId])
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @date datetime2(2) = '2018.07.10'
DECLARE @date2 datetime2(2) = '2018.08.10'

SELECT TOP 10 npl.NPId 
FROM [table] npl  
WHERE npl.RequestDate >= @date 
  AND npl.RequestDate < @date2 
ORDER BY npid
```

If I set order on requestDate then index is used.

Comment: So SQL Server decides that the filter is more important than the `order by`.

Comment: how many rows are there in the table? If there are too many then SQL Server might finds it efficient to process rows ordered by npid hoping to find first 10 matching rows.

Comment: Considering you're ordering by `NPid` and returning the `TOP 10` I'm guessing that the estimator decided that the CLUSTERED index is the better choice. Which it likely is, if that's the conclusion it made.

Comment: SQL Server will estimate that 30% of the rows match the `RequestDate` predicate (as the  actual values are hidden by variables so it must guess) and they are evenly distributed through the table so it only needs to read `33` to get the `TOP 10` ordered by `NPId`.  In reality the percent matching may be much lower as the daterange is only a month and they may be correlated w.r.t. `NPId ` so they are all clustered together and this is not a good plan... The alternative is to sort all rows matching the `RequestDate` range and then get the `TOP 10` which presumably it costs as more expensive

Comment: Actually 30% is the guess used for a single inequality predicate. For `>=` and `<` it will be a bit lower `(0.3) * SQRT(0.3) = 16.4%` ([dependant on CE version](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/t-sql-queries/paying-attention-estimates)) - so estimate `61` rows for getting the `TOP 10`

Comment: table has arround 83 million rows...

Comment: The larger the table the more likely you are to get the CI plan. It will assume it has to sort `16.4%` of 83 million rows (13.6 million) for the NCI plan - which is much more expensive than just reading 61 rows and stopping. The 61 row estimate won't change for the CI plan as more rows are added. But the number of rows it estimates it needs to sort will grow

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to reproduce.

Just inserting the following dummy data to the table in your question...

```
insert into [dbo].[table]
SELECT TOP 1000000 DATEADD(SECOND,  CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)% 1000000,GETDATE()) , 1, 1, 1, 1
FROM sys.all_objects o1, sys.all_objects o2
```

Then running

```
DECLARE @date datetime2(2) = '2018.07.10'
DECLARE @date2 datetime2(2) = '2018.08.10'

SELECT TOP 10 npl.NPId 
FROM [table] npl  
WHERE npl.RequestDate >= @date 
  AND npl.RequestDate < @date2 
ORDER BY npid
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9130) /*so filter visible in the plan*/


SELECT TOP 10 npl.NPId 
FROM [table] npl  WITH (INDEX = IX_ReqDate) 
WHERE npl.RequestDate >= @date 
  AND npl.RequestDate < @date2 
ORDER BY npid
```

[image]

The above are using `CardinalityEstimationModelVersion = 140` - similar will be seen in other versions of the CE though the exact numbers may be different.

1. The values used in the data range are hidden in variables so SQL Server assumes it will match `16.431676725155%` rows (`0.30*SQRT(0.30)`).
2. SQL Server also assumes that these rows will be distributed evenly throughout the table. So it assumes it needs to read 60.8581 (`10/(0.30*SQRT(0.30))`) before it gets 10 that match the predicate.
3. For the other plan it assumes it needs to sort 16.4% of the table which is costed as massively more expensive.

You can try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` so that SQL Server sniffs the date range used by the variable and it **may** reduce the 16.4% estimate enough to change the plan.

However probably more likely is that the estimates are reduced but not enough to change the plan and the CI plan is still undercosted (as the rows matching the range are not distributed evenly throughout the table and many more rows must be read than estimated). In that case you may consider using an index hint to get it to pick the index you want.